# Xamarin - How to implement two flyout pages?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How do you make 2 flyout pages in Xamarin?

I tried finding for solutions online and all seem to be only doing one side which really is just one line of code to pull off, `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`. What I'm looking for is how to put both left and right to use.

Comment: Won’t be able to use the built-in flyout page to do this. Make up your own solution from scratch, using a SwipeGestureRecognizer. It will be a lot of coding.

Comment: How exactly though? If it's refactoring a bunch of layouts to have the swipe gesture summon the flyout view from the right to the left, I would still go for it. How do you exactly make a page open up as a flyout page? Or is there a flyout page Nuget plugin I can use to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Look for examples like: https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/xamarin-forms-fancy-flyout-menu